# Mystery in extremely simple circuit

Tags: voltage, batteries

I have 3 pairs of wires from a battery, each pair goes to a lightbulb, two of them light up, I measure the voltage of the last pair as 10V, then I put a lightbulb in the third, and now the bulb doesnt light and the voltage here drops to 0, the other two bulbs still lights even though the voltage on last pair is 0, the third bulb works I tried it on the two other pairs, how is this possible? This is on an old boat, must there be some hidden circuitry?

Comment: Without a schematic, it's quite difficult to understand what you are describing.

Comment: Three pairs of wire from 1 battery, each pair leads to a lightbulb. Each pair is connected to the two poles of the battery. I dont understand how a working lightbulb can make the voltage drop to 0, and this without lighting up.

Comment: That's repeating the first sentence of your question, not a schematic. However, I'm confident your confusion is due to something you don't know, which we don't know either. Perhaps a component is faulty or the wrong type. Perhaps the circuit is not what you think it is. In any case, it's difficult to offer any insight without more information.

Comment: From your description, because there is a zero volt drop on the third bulb, I would want to say that the third bulb is shorted. However if this third bulb is indeed, in parallel with the other two bulbs, then these two should not light up since all the current would flow through the bulb. There must be additional circuitry to your description.

Comment: Maybe you can try reproducing the problem in a simpler circuit. No boat, no other two lightbulbs. If it still doesn't work, then include details about the kind of lightbulb, the kind of battery, and exactly how you connected them. Then the problem may be knowable.

Comment: It must be some additional circuitry, I will look into it tommorow.

Comment: Is the nominal battery voltage 10 V or something else?

Comment: 12V, it drops to around 11 with 1 bulb, and 10 with 2.

Comment: Are the other bulbs even relevant? What if you just put a bulb in the socket that doesn't work? What if you put that same bulb in a different socket? This is basic troubleshooting skill -- not electrical engineering. Please edit your question to include additional information.

Comment: It was indeed corrosion, no hidden circuitry. Cool problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me that there is high resistance (corroded connection) somewhere in the third set of wires. You then end up with effectively two resistors in series, a high resistance one (the wiring) and a low resistance one (the light bulb). In this case, most of the voltage will be dropped by the wiring and very little by the light bulb.

For example, assume that the light bulb is 1 ohm resistance and the wiring end up being 100 ohms. From a 12V battery, you will only see ~0.12V across the light.